# "bigint out of range" when computing factorial function in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin, factorial

As part of an intro to databases class, we've been told to create a function using PL/pgSQL that gives out a factorial of a number. Now since x! increases rapidly as a function, we've decided to return a `bigint` due to it being a large range integer.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getBigFactorial(fn bigint) RETURNS bigint as $$
DECLARE
 product bigint;
 minus1 int;
BEGIN
 if (fn > 21) then
 RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error: computing factorial; numeric value out of range';
 return NULL;
 elsif (fn < 1) then
 RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error: Argument less than 1!';
 return NULL;
 end if;
 
 minus1 := fn - 1;
 if (minus1 > 0) then
 product := fn * getBigFactorial(minus1);
 return product;
 end if;
 return fn;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

For this function, we've been told to create some sort of validation for the number entered.
The one for `(fn < 1)` worked flawlessly, however, the one which is `(fn > 21)` is giving some problems.

When the following is entered:

```sql
SELECT getBigFactorial(21);
```

We get:

```
ERROR:  bigint out of range
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function getbigfactorial(integer) line 17 at assignment
SQL state: 22003
```

rather than getting the desired output. Line 17 corresponds to this line:

```sql
 if (minus1 > 0) then
```

When we entered 22 instead of 21, we had the desired error output.

Any help in finding out what causes this?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional check should be inclusive of `21`:

```
if (fn >= 21) then
-- ...
```

since for an input of `21`, the factorial of 21 (`fn * getBigFactorial(minus1)`, where `fn` = 21, and `minus1` = `fn` - 1), which is an integer out of range for a `bigint`, is assigned to `product`, a `bigint`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We spent hours on end trying to find what was the problem! :)

Comment: Glad to save a few more =)